# PID of SSH port forwarding inside Docker not available

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, docker, sshd

I have 2 machines. There're my machine and a machine running SSH Docker container. Some service is running on my machine on a specified port and I'm doing port forwarding to SSHD container. Then I'm trying to terminate the forwarding (and SSH connection itself).

When doing port forwarding to second machine directly (connecting to normal, not dockerized SSHD) I'm able to locate the PID of the forwarding and therefore kill it.

`ssh -N -R 20030:127.0.0.1:20000 test@1.2.3.4 -p 22 -v`

`netstat` approach

```
root@host /home/username # netstat -antlp | grep 20030
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:20030 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 5918/sshd: username
tcp6 0 0 ::1:20030 :::* LISTEN 5918/sshd: username
root@host /home/username # kill -9 5918
```

`lsof` approach

```
root@host /home/username # lsof -n | grep 20030
sshd 6866 username 9u IPv6 1070467 0t0 TCP [::1]:20030 (LISTEN)
sshd 6866 username 10u IPv4 1070468 0t0 TCP 127.0.0.1:20030 (LISTEN)
root@host /home/username # kill -9 6866
```

Forwarding is terminated and SSH connection as well since I requested forwarding only with SSH `-N` option.

However when using SSHD inside Docker container situation is not so straightforward.

Let's say container's SSHD runs on port 2222. I'm doing port forwarding.

`ssh -N -R 20030:127.0.0.1:20000 test@1.2.3.4 -p 2222 -v`

Then I enter the container and try the same approaches as before.

`netstat` approach

```
root@f9702d3087f0:/# netstat -antlp | grep 20030
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:20030 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN -
tcp6 0 0 :::20030 :::* LISTEN -
```

`lsof` approach

```
root@f9702d3087f0:/# lsof -n | grep 20030
root@f9702d3087f0:/#
```

Please notice I'm not able to locate PID of the forwarding now. How Docker container is different than connecting directly to host and what can be done to kill the forwarding on SSHD side? I'm not interested in doing it on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the container with this option: `docker run [...] --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE`

When using Docker Compose add this to your container's definition:

```
    cap_add:
        - SYS_PTRACE
```

What does it do? From Docker documentation:

> SYS_PTRACE    Trace arbitrary processes using ptrace(2).